# Starting a RESTful API in Java EE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, rest

My work is going to be taking on a RESTful API project that will be built in Java-EE and JAX-RS.  I'm very interested in getting a jump start on learning Java-EE and building this type of application because I definitely want to be involved as to take full advantage of the opportunity to learn.  I have a background with PHP/Javascript/MySQL.  I'm not entirely sure if MySQL will be the database of choice, but right now I need to assume it will be.

What's the best way to setup a RESTful API?  What are things that need to be considered?  How should security be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent tutorial that might get you started in the right direction:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/

Choice of database is relatively unimportant (at least for learning purposes).

If you don't already know Java, then you should definitely dedicate time to learning it.  I'd recommend Headfirst Java as a good introduction:

[http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)